# Understanding the behavior of dbms_random.value in where clause

Tags: oracle

I have a table with two columns(Using oracle 11g database) : Country, IndexNumber. Table contains 10 rows(10 different cities and with its unique index number.)

For example:

```
Country      IndexNUmber
India         1
Australia     2
.             .
.             .
.             .
.             .
US            10
```

Now i want to fetch a random row from above table by generating random number using `dbms_random.value(1,10`). To achieve that i am using below query:

```
select * from tab_name where indexnumber = dbms_random.value(1,10);
```

I am not able to understand the output of this query as some time it is fetching one row, some time zero rows and some time more that one row.

Can someone please make me understand how oracle is evaluating this query.

Thanks 
Ankit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `dbms_random.value` is a nondeterministic PL/SQL function, it will be called once for each row evaluated by the query.

The function might return 4 when evaluating the first row, then it might return 8 on the second row, etc.

To compare each row to a single random number, you can turn the function call into a scalar subquery, e.g.:

```
select * from tab_name where indexnumber = (select dbms_random.value(1,10) from dual);
```

Since the subquery is not correlated to the main query, Oracle will execute it only once (for the first row returned from the table) and remember the result for all subsequent rows. In particular, if a suitable index is on `indexnumber` the query will be able to use it more efficiently since it knows it is probing for a single value.

Comment: Thanks jeffrey, this gives me a more clearer picture.

Comment: Thanks, this helped explain the behaviour I was seeing, and led me to try to understand the functions more.

Answer (score 0):

When you run your original query:

```
select * from tab_name where indexnumber = dbms_random.value(1,10);
```

it appears that the call to `dbms_random` is happening for each record's `where` clause.  In other words, there is a chance that every record in your table might be returned if the random number chosen happen to match the index for every record.  If you want to retrieve a single random record, then follow this pattern:

```
select *
from
( select * from tab_name order by DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE )
where rownum < 2;
```

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for the response. I want to understand why it is happening like this. Can you give me an explanation for this behavior.

Comment: @user3266179 The query in your question is a good example.  The only way I can explain it is that the random call is being computed for each record in the `WHERE` clause.  Hence, you can get things like multiple records appearing in the result set.